# Java: Substitute consecutive numbers in a matrix

Tags: java, matrix, counter

I need a way to find a consecutive series of numbers in a matrix and replace them with 1 and all other numbers with 0, moving as though it was a snake. Let me put an example which will hopefully make it easier to understand:

```
9 2 9
9 6 8
9 9 4
```

This matrix should turn into:

```
1 0 0
1 0 0
1 1 0
```

Right now what I have is this:

```
public int[][] replace(int[][] numbers, int n) {
    int[][] temp = numbers;
    int cont = 0;
    int cont2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (i < n - 1 && temp[cont][cont2] == temp[cont + 1][cont2]) {
                numbers[cont][cont2] = 1;
                numbers[cont + 1][cont2] = 1;
                cont++;
            }
            if (j < n - 1 && temp[cont][cont2] == temp[cont][cont2 + 1]) {
                numbers[0][1] = 1;
                numbers[0][0] = 1;
                cont2++;
            }
        }
        cont2 = 0;
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

It only barely works, replacing only like the first 2 values and then stops doing it for some reason. Im also missing the validation to check numbers to the left of the current number; and the part to make all other numbers 0 which shouldnt be too hard.

Anyone got any ideas what i need to change to make this work?

Comment: When you say "consecutive series of numbers" do you mean adjacent numbers that are the same? Also, are you looking for adjacent numbers of a certain number, or any numbers that are adjacent and the same? For instance if you had a 3x3 grid where the first column was three 1's, the second column was three 2's, and the third column was three 3's, would the entire board be changed to 1's, or just a specific column?

Comment: yeah, adjacent numbers that are the same, And i forgot to say they have to be the same to the first element ([0][0])

Comment: Do the group(s) have to include the first element? For example, if you have a 3x3 where the first column is 1's, the second column is 2's, and the third column is also 1's, would both the first and third columns count as valid groups, or just the first since it contains the first element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I found some problems or I misunderstand some points in your algorithm:

```
public int[][] replace(int[][] numbers, int n) {
    int[][] temp = numbers; // /!\ temp points to the same array as numbers
    int cont = 0;  // why not using i
    int cont2 = 0; // why not using j
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (i < n - 1 && temp[cont][cont2] == temp[cont + 1][cont2]) {
                numbers[cont][cont2] = 1; // /!\ temp=numbers is also modified
                numbers[cont + 1][cont2] = 1;
                cont++; // /!\ ~= i*j => index out of bound
            }
            if (j < n - 1 && temp[cont][cont2] == temp[cont][cont2 + 1]) {
                numbers[0][1] = 1; // why fixed indexes ?
                numbers[0][0] = 1;
                cont2++;
            }
        }
        cont2 = 0; // cont2 seems equivalent to j
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

Do you want something like this (I haven't tested it):

```
public int[][] replace(int[][] numbers, int n) {
    int[][] result=new int[n][n];
    int ref = numbers[0][0];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (numbers[i][j]==ref) {
                boolean isAdj=false;
                if(i>0) isAdj=isAdj || numbers[i-1][j]==ref;
                if(i<n-1) isAdj=isAdj || numbers[i+1][j]==ref;
                if(j>0) isAdj=isAdj || numbers[i][j-1]==ref;
                if(j<n-1) isAdj=isAdj || numbers[i][j+1]==ref;
                if(isAdj) result[i][j]=1;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The specification of the problem already contains an issues: What to do when there are two lines of numbers? The solution itself can be found pretty simple using DFS (or alternatively BFS), or any other path-finding algorithm. This topic is covered pretty well though, so I won't post any code here.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell, as your intent is confusing, but within your `for` loop you have two consecutive `if` statements.  As the first statement can change the value of a variable used in the second statement's condition expression, I wonder if you should have an `else` instead of an  `if` on the second one ?

Answer (score 0):

What your current overall idea does (as far as I can tell and regardless of bugs in your code) is it looks for similar numbers in a single path that only goes down and to the right. This idea just won't work in all cases. If you come across a block of numbers that goes down then up, then it won't change all of them. For instance, given

```
2 1 2
2 1 2
2 2 2
```

Your algorithm will start at the top left corner and go down and then right, but not back up to finish the U shape.

Secondly, the line `int[][] temp = numbers;` means that any changes you make to `temp` are made to `numbers` and vice versa. It is what is known as a shallow copy since only the references are copied, not the data they reference. You probably want a deep copy.

The simple answer is to use a flood fill algorithm. Flood fill basically fills an arbitrary area by searching the overall board as much as it can while following the rules of what defines the area to fill. Everywhere it can explore successfully, it drops a "breadcrumb" (special value) at that location, then you can go back and change it to whatever it needs to be.

The following flood fill algorithm uses a depth first search to explore the area to fill. If you want to do a breadth first search, just switch out the stack for a priority queue.

```
import java.awt.Point;   //just an integer based point object for the Stack
import java.util.Stack;   //get the Stack

public int[][] replace(int[][] numbers, int n) {
    int value = numbers[0][0];        //value we are looking for
    int[] rowChange = {-1, 0, 1, 0};  //for easy direction checking
    int[] colChange = {0, 1, 0, -1};

    // for the breadcrumbs; initialized to 0, so make a breadcrumb equal to 1
    // then the resulting breadcrumb matrix will be what you want
    int[][] breadcrumbs = new int[numbers.length][numbers[0].length];
    Stack<Point> toExplore = new Stack<Point>();
    toExplore.push(new Point(0, 0));   //explore the first point

    // we are using Point.y as the row (first index),
    // and Point.x as the column (second index)

    //while there is a location to explore
    while (toExplore.size() > 0) {
        Point center = toExplore.pop();

        // drop a breadcrumb
        breadcrumbs[center.y][center.x] = 1;

        // explore in the 4 cardinal directions
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            int row = center.y + rowChange[i];
            int col = center.x + colChange[i];

            // make sure we haven't already been here (bounds check first)
            if ((row >= 0) && (row < numbers.length) &&    // bounds check
                (col >= 0) && (col < numbers[0].length) &&
                (breadcrumbs[row][col] == 0) &&            // make sure we haven't been there already
                (numbers[row][col] == value))              // make sure it has the right value there
            {
                toExplore.push(new Point(col, row));
            }
        }
    }

    // filled with 1's where we explored and 0's where we didn't
    return breadcrumbs;
}
```

**UPDATE**
Built and ran the code, and it works.